# iOS: My tableView is not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have an issue with my iOS application. It is a simple iOS web browser.

My tableView is visible in Xcode xib but not shown while running simulator. I have implemented `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate` protocols and following methods:

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Here is my `AppDelegate.h class`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Here is my [AppDelegate.m](http://pastebin.com/SatDZJcp) class

Here is my `History&Favorites.h class`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface History_Favorites : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableWithBookmarks;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *URLs;

@end
```

Here is my [History&Favorites.m](http://pastebin.com/GfT8z7Jz) class

I will be grateful for any advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is my xib file with tableView that is not shown when I run the app.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/XAR6m.png

Comment: Does [self.URLs count] return something different from 0 in numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: can you show the code how you implemented `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: did u connected the `dataSource` and `delegate` of `tableWithBookmarks` from interface?

Comment: Does the delegate methods get called?

Comment: @Rafouille, NSMutableArray URLs contains 2 objects. It is implemented in History&Favorites.m in  -(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil method. Even if I change this [self.URLs count] to any integer - I see white empty screen without table rows.

Comment: heightforrowatindexpath is not found

Comment: @Diana please **edit the question** and format it as code :)

Comment: and btw, aren't you using ARC, or why are you calling autorelease? maybe that has something to do with the issue?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr, yes, I Have connected both protocols. Please,go link in my firs comment.

Comment: try adding `[self.tableWithBookmarks reloadData];` in `viewDidLoad` and also move `self.URLs` initialisation and addObjects to `viewDidLoad` from `initWithNibName:`

Comment: @nburk, sure. I don't use ARC in this project. I created such project month ago with ARM and it worked as should do. I guess that it doesn't work maybe because I didn't implement method **pushViewController:animated:** But I really don't know where I should do this and how - I'm novice in iOS developing. I also trying to find answers for this question.

Comment: @CarouselMin it is not a required method, so I didn't use it.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr, the same result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the following :

```
@synthesize tableWithBookmarks;
```

Update the **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method with the following :

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *hiddenCell = [tableWithBookmarks dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (hiddenCell == nil)
{
    hiddenCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]autorelease];
}

hiddenCell.textLabel.text = @"Detail"; 
//[self.URLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//History_Favorites *historyView = [[History_Favorites alloc]init];
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:historyView animated:YES];

return hiddenCell;
```

Comment: Thanks to you and this row `UITableViewCell *hiddenCell = [tableWithBookmarks dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];` I find another mistake in my code. But my issue is still not solved.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer did not help. The problem was that my class had the '&' symbol in it's name. Thanks anyway for your contribution.